# How to use Ajax in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ajax, json

After reading several articles about Ajax in ROR, I am still confused about how to use Ajax!

There is a `main/index.html` and `main_controller` in my project. I want to fulfill the function described as below:

Once the link in the `index.html` is clicked, the RSS content will show up in the index. I have fulfill the function by jumping to another webpage. But I don't know how to use Ajax...

## index

```
 <h1>Listing Jobs</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= job.source %></td>
        <td>
            <%= link_to 'Show', #:controller=>'main', :action=>'show',
                :id=>job.id,:remote=>true, "data-type"=>:json, :class=>'updateJob'%>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table> 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(function(){
#   $('#'+job.id).bind("click",function(){
#       $('#showJob').append('Hi')
#   })

$('#'+job.id).bind("ajax:success",function(data, status, xhr){
    ("<h1>hello</h1>").appendTo("#showJob") 
})

})
</script>
```

## show.html

```
<div id="showJob">
    </div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Link</th>
    </tr>
<% @feed.items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
        <th><%= item.title %></th>
        <th><%= item.link  %></th>
    </tr>
<% end %>

</table>
```

## main_controller

```
require 'rss'
require 'rss/1.0'
require 'rss/2.0'
require 'open-uri'

class MainController < ApplicationController
    #get /jobs
    def index
        @jobs=Job.all

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.json {render:json=>@jobs}
        end
    end

    def welcome
        @num_sources =Job.count
    end

    def show
        job=Job.find(params[:id])
        url=job.url
        open(url) do |rss|
            @feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
        end

        respond_to do |format|
        # format.html do
        #   render :partial=>'main/show'
        # end
        format.json {render :json=>@feed}
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding to the `click` event, add bindings for the ajax events that you want to handle.  Typically, this would include the `ajax:success` event:

```
$(function(){
    $('#'+job.id).on("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr){
        // do something with 'data' json object
    });
});
```

A complete list of events can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax).

To have the controller use the 'json' format when rendering, change your link to look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', { :controller=>'main', :action=>'show', :id=>job.id }, 
                    :data => {:remote=>true, :type=>:json}, :class=>'updateJob'%>
```

Note that the hash that makes up the url (controller, action, id) needs to be passed in a separate hash from the other attributes to work properly.  You can make this even simpler if you have your job set up as a resource in your `routes.rb` file:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', job, :data => {:remote=>true, :type=>:json}, :class=>'updateJob'%>
```

Comment: I still don't know how to deal with controller. In the "show" method of the controller, the "format.html" will bring me to the show.html instead of showing the content partially...